# How to know if my GPU supports CUDA?

Tags: cuda

How can I know from the terminal or something whether my hardware supports CUDA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Using the browser to find CUDA**

1. Open `Chrome` browser
2. Goto the url `chrome://gpu`
3. Search for `cuda` and you should get the version detected (in my case, not enabled)

[image]

Comment: If that shows 0, the hardware may still support CUDA, but the drivers simply are not installed/working.  It shows 0 on my laptop, but GPU-Z says my hardware supports CUDA 1.2

Comment: it is almost useless answer ... "almost" cause chrome suggests you to install the latest official drivers :D https://askubuntu.com/a/1450399/652604

Answer (score 8):

> CUDA works with all Nvidia GPUs from the G8x series onwards, including GeForce, Quadro and the Tesla line. CUDA is compatible with most standard operating systems.

For a list of supported graphic cards, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).

Comment: I have an onboard graphics chip.

Comment: You didn't tell me that earlier. What is your motherboard manufacturer and model? Does it have a Nvidia graphic processor?

Comment: I don't know. How can I tell without opening my chasis?

Comment: A system diagnostic program called speccy is available that will tell you everything you need: http://www.piriform.com/speccy

Comment: I think speccy doesn't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: These pages have system information programs for Ubuntu and other Linux OS: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-get-your-system-information-with-sysinfo.html http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-get-hardware-information-in.html

Comment: Thanks. I like `lshw`. From what I gather, I have a "Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller" from Intel. Will it support CUDA?

Comment: No, only Nvidia controllers use CUDA.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Just one more: Will my chip support OpenCL?

Comment: Ask that in another question because I don't know the answer. The person who does will need to know which graphics controller you have.

Answer (score 1):

(2021 update)

1. CUDA software API is supported on Nvidia GPUs, through the software drivers provided by Nvidia.
2. If your desktop has a Nvidia GPU, AND you have the Nvidia drivers installed (for ex from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), an executable that uses CUDA can be built using CUDA toolkit, as outlined at -

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/

3. To compile a CUDA application specifically for your GPU, the compute capability of the specific GPU is required, and this can be obtained by following the steps outlined at

https://github.com/prabindh/mygpu

(I am the author of that web tool)

Manually, you could use nvidia-smi that is installed along with the driver

> nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv

Or use driver information to obtain GPU name and map it to Compute capability.

Answer (score 0):

1. CUDA support is shown in official nvidia website, for example my [geforce-gtx-1060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/graphics-cards/geforce-gtx-1060/specifications/)
2. In case it is supported and you have **LTS Ubuntu version**:

   - install nvidia-driver with CUDA support from [official CUDA repository](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#network-repo-installation-for-ubuntu)